# Laravel, Lost data in Custom Request class

Tags: php, laravel-5

I store some data in a middleware as following:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   //checking above..
    if($this->authed()){
        $request->token= $token; //here store the token in user request
        return $next($request);
    }
    return response('Invalid credentials', 401);
}
```

then in controller I call a custom request class

```
//function in controller
public function upload(CoverageValueRequest $request){ //calling a custom request
    dd($request->token);
    dd($request->all());
}
```

the first dd will give null. However if I changed `CoverageValueRequest` to `Request` it will print the token.

P.S: the $request data coming from REST call as JSON format using Content-Type: application/json. I am not sure if this is relevant.

**update**

I have changed the following in the middleware still same behavior:

```
$request->merge(['token' => $token]);
```

can't get the token if `CoverageValueRequest` but if it is `Request` then it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer by setting token as attribute to request, the middleware class:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
   //checking above..
   if($this->authed()){
      $request->attributes->add(['token' => $token]);
      return $next($request);
    }
    return response('Invalid credentials', 401);
}
```

then retrieve it in the controller as following:

```
//function in controller
public function upload(CoverageValueRequest $request){ //calling a custom request
   dd($request->attributes->get('token'));
   dd($request->all());
}
```

I am not sure why the weird behavior of direct assigning or `merge` didn't work. Hope someone can clarify.